# Any jobs that offer lots of vacation, and low stress?

Tags: career-development, stress

I’m 45 years old and am looking to semi retire.  I have enough money to retire but would like to stay somewhat busy and also have health insurance.  The job pay doesn’t matter to me but what matters is ability to take time off and most important for it to be low stress.  I don’t want to think about the job outside the office as I will be focused on other things when not working.  The problem with my job now is that it requires lots of thinking outside of work hours and is stressful.  I thought about teaching but have been told it requires lots of work outside of job hours.

Comment: Depends what stresses you out? Everyone is different. For example I could recommend working in customer service as a receptionist but some people find this stressful as it means communicating with others, however some people love this type of job. I think it all comes down to narrowing down a set of jobs you enjoy and go from there with the issue on thinking outside of work etc..

Comment: You may want to add a location tag, things like which jobs provide health insurance benefits will be different based on locality.

Comment: How much is "lots of vacation"?  At some point that becomes part-time work and getting benefits from the employer in that scenario might be tough.

Comment: Kind of depends on your profession, you didnt mention what you do

Comment: The fact is for "computer programmers" many if not most just work on a contract or freelance basis. This gives you 100% flexibility to take off as much time as you want.  (I do that!) Secondly you can work from home, or indeed, anywhere you choose.  So for a "holiday" you can go live in Barcelona or whatever for a few months - and still work every day - and your only cost is housing - which need be no more than in your "usual" city. Stress - can be zero depending on the field.  Unfortunately, you can't "just learn" to be a programmer, it would be like "just learning" to be a session guitarist.

Comment: Ah, you generally get no health insurance, contracting/freelancing.

Comment: My parents have been teaching their whole life to teenagers, and I'm quite sure they would not agree on teaching being low stress and no work home...

Answer (score 7):

The answer is going to be really specific to what drives you, and what stresses you. Also, what your own career has been to date - if you don't have the resume for a specific job, it may not make sense to pursue it.

You mentioned teaching, that was the first thing that came to mind - you get a lot of time off, good benefits, etc - but clearly, it can be "stressful" to some people (ie if you don't like kids!)

Meanwhile, my neighbor works for the post office, delivering mail. He loves the low stress aspect - there's no way for him to "take work home" at the end of the day. Once he's delivered to the last house, he's done. He goes home and doesn't give work a second thought until the next morning. He gets to walk through town every day and talks to the same people on a regular basis - he's an extrovert so that's great for him! Good benefits (vacation time and health insurance) too.

Comment: He often jokes, "it would be illegal for me to bring my work home!" but jokes aside, it's a great point - not only can he not bring work home or work from home, there's absolutely nothing for him to fret over after hours, or lay awake at night trying to figure out. When he's delivered the last piece of mail for the day, he's literally done. The work is very discrete in nature with an obvious, and predictable, start and finish point every day. For a lot of people, that sort of predictability, and the fact that problems or projects can't carry over from day to day means "no stress."

Comment: "there's absolutely nothing for him to fret over after hours"  it is **VERY** hard to achieve that feeling.